# How to connect to docker-machine via its ip adress (hyper-v)

Tags: docker, docker-machine, hyper-v, nestjs

I have a backend that I want to run in a Docker container in order to connect to it from another computer or device.

I created an external virtual switch on a hyper-v machine and created a new virtual machine that is connected to this switch. By the command:

```
docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch <NameOfVirtualSwitch> <nameOfNode>
```

I connect to this external virtual switch in the network settings

There are a set of commands that I use to run

```
docker container prune
docker image prune
docker build -t nestjsdocker:latest .
docker run -it -p 3001:3001 --name {here are id of image} nestjsdocker:latest
```

There is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

When I type `docker-machine ip {name of my vm}` I get 10.10.0.242, but when I type in the browser like http://10.10.0.242:3001/ I get error 'This site can’t be reached'

Comment: What response are you expecting by opening it with your browser?

Comment: @nPcomp I try it, but always get a message like 'This site can't be reached'